# Getting the name of a tabled copied from another page

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a macro that will copy a table to various other pages where it will then sort those pasted tables to a particular date range. My problem is knowing the table name of the newly copied table. I tried to just do a simple count but the default number assigned to list objects are apparently not chronological. When I got to the 199th table copied, the next table copied was 1100 instead of 200...

The table pasted onto the worksheet is the only table on that sheet so I *think* I should be able to either be able to assign the name or get what ever name was assigned automatically. How do I do that? Or do I need to copy the table in a completely different way?

```
Option Explicit
Dim DutyQueue As Worksheet
Dim MonthQueue As Worksheet
Dim tblNum As Integer
Dim tblOld As Integer
Dim intWSCount As Integer
Dim intmonth As Date
Dim endmonth As Date

Sub CopyMonthlyDutyLoop()

Set DutyQueue = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Duty Queue")

For intWSCount = 4 To 15
Set MonthQueue = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(intWSCount)
tblNum = DutyQueue.Cells(1, 1)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(intWSCount).Activate
tblOld = MonthQueue.Cells(1, 1)
intmonth = MonthQueue.Cells(1, 2)
endmonth = MonthQueue.Cells(1, 3)

'copy table from Duty Queue
DutyQueue.Range("Table1[#All]").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(intWSCount).Range("A2")

'sort for all tasks due for the month
tblNum = tblNum + 1
Worksheets(intWSCount).ListObjects("Table_I_Just_Copied").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<=" & intmonth, Operation:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & endmonth


DutyQueue.Cells(1, 1) = tblNum
MonthQueue = Worksheets(intWSCount).ListObjects("Table_I_Just_Copied").Name


Next intWSCount

End Sub
```

Comment: `worksheets("nnn").listobjects(1).name` ?

Comment: I get an error that the method or property isn't supported.

Comment: @SJR, I'm not sure what I did wrong the first time trying your suggestion but in further tinkering, this answer was absolutely correct. Do you want to put it as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference a table using its index (as with any collection), and if you have only one table on a sheet it becomes simpler to identify that table, viz:

```
Worksheets("nnn").listobjects(1).name
```